# extending bootstrap select

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the bootstrap framework along with http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/. it just doesnt work. Below are the codes. Please help.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Final_Year_Project_Allocation_System.silviomoreto_bootstrap_select_d4ec9bd.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    

    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
    <select class="selectpicker">
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
</select>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

please help.

Comment: Does the error console report any errors? Can you verify that all scripts are loading?

Comment: You still have `bootstrap-select.css` twice (after your edit). `bootstrap.css` is still not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reference to the actual `bootstrap.css` ?
You need to have something like (note the order - it's important):

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then the JS

```
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Make sure the path is correct* of course.

**EDIT**

I'm also pretty sure that boostrap.js has a dependency on jquery - so make sure you include it as well (***before*** the bootsrap.js).

**EDIT 2**

I also suspect that your paths are not correct. If this is the path for your javascript:

```
"../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
```

Then most probably the path for your css would be (assuming that you just dropped bootstrap as-is and didn't place it in a different folder):

```
"../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
```